# HISTIGNORE not working in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have added

```
export HISTIGNORE="ls:cd:pwd:exit:cd .."
```

to my .zshrc file.

Deleted .zsh_history and restarted terminal but it still wont ignore those commands.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The `zsh` shell doesn't use the `HISTIGNORE` environment variable. Instead, it has a `HISTORY_IGNORE` environment variable.

From the [`zshparam` manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell):

> `HISTORY_IGNORE`
>
> If set, is treated as a pattern at the time history files are
>                 written.   Any  potential history entry that matches the pattern is skipped.  For example, if the value is  `fc  *`  then
>                 commands that invoke the interactive history editor are never
>                 written to the history file.
>
> Note that `HISTORY_IGNORE` defines a single pattern: to specify
>                 alternatives use the `(first|second|...)` syntax.

So in your case, you would want to do

```
HISTORY_IGNORE="(ls|cd|pwd|exit|cd ..)"
```

or something similar.

Notice that this affects only history written to the history file, not the history in the currently active shell session, as far as I can see.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working still. I am using .oh-my-zsh, don't know if that changes those variables. I was following this guys examples
https://github.com/bradp/dotfiles/blob/master/sourced/exports

which is why I was thinking it would work that way. But I am not sure anymore.

Comment: Well, setting `SAVEHIST` to a positive number, making sure that `HISTFILE` is set to the name of a history file, and setting `HISTORY_IGNORE` to `"(cd|ls)"` definitely works as advertised by the `zsh` manual in any case.

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda. I think you are right. I thought and was hoping that this would stop those commands from being shown when I ran 'history' or when i hit the up key. They are not in the history file though so i guess it is working.

Comment: @tgreen Did you figure out how to make it stop showing ignored entries when pressing up/down?

Comment: The docs are not very clear. What means "pattern" is that a regex?

Comment: @kev It would be a globbing pattern rather than a regular expression.

Comment: `HISTORY_IGNORE` needs to be set to `"(cd|ls)*"` to match the whole command with arguments; `"(cd|ls)"` only applies to exact match like `cd` not `cd /foo/bar/`.

Comment: @Saftever Yes, but if you set `HISTORY_IGNORE` to `"(cd|ls)*"` you would also weed out any _other_ command that starts with `cd` or `ls` though, so you may want `"(cd|cd *|ls|ls *)"`, or `"(cd(| *)|ls(| *))"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda good point. For my use case, `"(cd|ls) *"` is sufficient because I mainly want to exclude the arguments from history, e.g. exclude `ls /top/secret/location`, but `ls` is ok.